# Verify that one instance method calls another

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

For example we have a cron job that returns a result set. I need to be able to test that the `runjobs` method called the correct method depending on a mock result set.

```
function runJobs($results) {
    foreach (results as $row) {
        if ($row->blah === 'condition') {
            $this->runJobA($row);
        } else {
            $this->runJobB($row);
        }
    }
}

function runJobA($row) {
    //do something
}

function runJobB($row) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to implement it using partial mocks.

Quick and untested proposal:

```
$mock = $this->createMock('classname', array('runJobA', 'runJobB'));

$mock->expects($this->once())
     ->method('runJobA');

$mock->runJobs(...);
```

If you specify particular method names as a second argument of a `createMock()` method then phpunit mock library generates so called partial mock.

In comparison with "normal" mocks - in partial mocks all the methods use the existing *real* implementation, but the ones you specified would be mocked.

Comment: I suspect this is the answer but I had refactored my code to use gontrollez solution by the time I read this.

Comment: @BobB: I would say it's a bad practice to expose the method to be called just to make your code testable

Answer (score 1):

Get the decission code to a class:

```
class JobSelector
{
     public function getJobRunnerMethodName($results)
     {
         // some logic here for getting JobA or JobB
         $method = "runJobA";
         return $method;
     }
}
```

Now you can test it:

```
public function testJobAMethodReturnedWhenBlah()
{
    $sut = new JobSelector();
    $result = "blah";
    $this->assertEquals('runJobA', $sut->getJob($result));
}

public function testJobBMethodReturnedWhenBlah()
{
     ....
}
```

Aditionally, you can implement each job in it's own class, and make the JobSelector class return a Job instance. Then you test the Job type returned instead of the method name. And your code would become:

```
$job_selector = new JobSelector();
$job = $job_selector->getJob();
$job->run();
```

Comment: I refactored my code to make this work. Doesn't actually answer the question but does solve my problem so thanks.